# Is deodorant allowed on Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, smell, personal-hygiene

May deodorant be applied on Yom Kippur, or is it a case of anointing which is forbidden?

Comment: Stick? Spray?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @DoubleAA Both.

Comment: תוספות מסכת יומא דף עז עמוד א
ר"ת דכל עינויים דיוה"כ ליתנהו אלא מדרבנן כללא דמילתא היכא דאינו בשביל תענוג שרי In my opinion
ק"ו במקום כבוד הבריאות

Answer (score 5):

The Shulchan Aruch (OC 614:1) rules:

> אסור לסוך אפילו מקצת גופו, ואפילו אינו אלא להעביר הזוהמא
>   It is forbidden to anoint even a part of ones body, even if it is only to remove bad filth/odor/?.

[This site](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/09/09/deodorant-on-yom-kippur/) cites Rav Elyashiv as recommending against spray deodorant because it is a "cosmetic", implying that on a more basic level it should be permitted. They take it for granted that stick deodorant is problematic.

Comment: I'll just warn not to immediately extrapolate to Tisha b'av.

Comment: I heard from R. M. Willig that it is forbidden on both, though some disagree.

Comment: @ArielK Stick? Spray?

Comment: spray, stick is just more of an issue

Comment: What about roll on?

Comment: @shachna nira that roll on and spray have the same din.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=257