# What modern-day hygiene products are prohibited on Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, technology, yom-kippur, oil, personal-hygiene

What, if any, modern-day hygiene products are prohibited "oils" on Yom Kippur?

Are deodorants and perfumes in this category? What about medical ointments?

Comment: Are you excluding those prohibited because of "washing"?

Comment: Either way people should go easy on the perfumes. Assuming they're not prohibited outright, some people can't tolerate the smell very well while fasting.

Comment: @double aa, are some prohibited BC of washing?

Comment: Sorta dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20390/is-deodorant-allowed-on-yom-kippur

Comment: @DoubleAA only sorta.